# listview does not work on fragment - OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate

Tags: android, memory-leaks

`ListView` does not work on fragments, I tried some codes on this, but again it continues to say - "the app is stopped"

**My Main Activity**

```
public class OrtaMain extends Fragment {

    private ListView listView;
    private  int[] user_poster_resources={
            R.drawable.home,
            R.drawable.home,
            R.drawable.home,
            R.drawable.home,
            R.drawable.home,
            R.drawable.home
    };
    private int[] alt_resource={
            R.drawable.home,
            R.drawable.home,
            R.drawable.home,
            R.drawable.home,
            R.drawable.home,
            R.drawable.home
    };

    private String[] konu_basliks;
    private String[] konu_tarihs;
    private String[] konu_iceriks;
    OrtaMainAdapter adapter;

    public OrtaMain() { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view       = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_orta_main, container, false);
        listVie         = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.orta_main_liste);
        konu_basliks    = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.strin_baslik);
        konu_tarihs     = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.konu_tarih);
        konu_iceriks    = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.konu_icerik);

        int i = 0;
        adapter = new OrtaMainAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.ortamain_item);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        for (String basliklar:konu_basliks) {
            OrtaMainDataProvider dataProvider = new OrtaMainDataProvider(basliklar);
            adapter.add(dataProvider);
            i++;
        }
        return view; 
    }
}
```

**Data Provider**

```
public class OrtaMainDataProvider {
    private String baslik;

    public OrtaMainDataProvider(String baslik) {
        this.setBaslik(baslik);
    }

    public String getBaslik() {
        return baslik;
    }

    public void setBaslik(String baslik) {
        this.baslik = baslik;
    }
}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
public class OrtaMainAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    List list = new ArrayList();

    public OrtaMainAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(@Nullable Object object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    static class DataHandler{
        TextView konu_baslik;
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return this.list.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.list.get(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View row;
        row = convertView;
        DataHandler handler;

        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ortamain_item, parent, false);
            handler = new DataHandler();
            handler.konu_baslik = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.orta_main_baslik);
            row.setTag(handler);
        }
        else{
            handler = (DataHandler) row.getTag();
        }

        OrtaMainDataProvider dataProvider;
        dataProvider= (OrtaMainDataProvider) this.getItem(position);
        handler.konu_baslik.setText(dataProvider.getBaslik());

        return row;
    }
}
```

and **logcat information**

```
06-27 14:31:37.836 11336-11336/com.example.cc.trafikprojesi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.cc.trafikprojesi, PID: 11336
                                                                          java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 80281612 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 42MB until OOM
                                                                              at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                              at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                              at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                                                                              at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                                              at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:973)
                                                                              at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2423)
                                                                              at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
                                                                              at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
                                                                              at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
                                                                              at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:135)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:60)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:56)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087)
```

Those codes are working well on any simple activity. When I test anothers. but when i put those codes, the listview does not work and emulator is stopping..

Also, fragment works well when I don't put the `ListView` code, and fragment give error and does not work on emulator.

Do `ListView` not work on fragments? Must I put only on nonfragments?

Comment: It's possible to have a `ListView` in a fragment, provide your logcat error.

Comment: logcat error ?? you mean log events on android studio ?

Comment: `MenuBar --> Window --> Show view --> Other --> logcat` - Here you can find exception in red . But yes, just add any exception you got.

Comment: Also, please further clarify your last paragraph because they make no sense, I was trying to fix it for you but I have no idea what you are trying to say, I'm sorry.

Comment: thank u bro.. i found logcat now.. i found the error.. let me on put the topic for get well..

Comment: but i dont know how i can fix in the OrtaMainAdapter line: 63 " LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ortamain_item, parent, false);" .. its true codes when i test on another activity..

Comment: You have a Memory problem here, just look at the first line in your logcat , you are trying to load too much into memory. Are you working with Images? - `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 80281612 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 42MB`

Comment: yes bro.. but only 6 example image.. its again problem ???

Comment: all arrray has same size?

Comment: string arrays ?? nope.. its post picture.. like wallpaper..

Comment: Here's what I recommend, not good enough for an answer but it should help... You can ignore the problem *not recommended* and increase the heapSize by adding this to your android manifest file - `<application android:largeHeap="true"` or you can profile your application with LeakCanry - https://github.com/square/leakcanary

Comment: It's also worth saying that you can reduce the memory required for your Bitmaps by using the `Bitmap.Config` type `RGB_565` instead of `ARGB_8888`.

Comment: let me try bro..

Comment: wow bro u r super.. it worked.. thank u very much :)) .. pls let me accept ur answer.. can u give the answer below comment for me to accept ur answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I recommend,  it should help...

You can ignore the problem ***not recommended*** and increase the heapSize by adding this to your android manifest file:

`<application android:largeHeap="true"`

Also set `Bitmap.Config` type `RGB_565` instead of `ARGB_8888` to keep the bitmaps smaller.

But the best option here would be to take some time and profile your application with [LeakCanary](http://github.com/square/leakcanary) and take a look at this video to learn Memory Management for Android - [Google I/O 2011: Memory management for Android Apps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk) (Play from [4:12](https://youtu.be/_CruQY55HOk?t=412) to see why `largeHeap=true` is bad.) then at [8:31](https://youtu.be/_CruQY55HOk?t=831) they go into detail on understanding heap usage.

The large heap fix it's a temporary fix and shouldn't be considered final. I highly recommend profiling, Take a look at the [Fragment life cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) the method that is called before the Fragment is completely done with is the `onDetach()` method, you may want to release all the resources here. The fact that a fragment itself is destroyed and gc'ed does not mean all resources you allocated were removed.

Comment: You are very welcome, I'm updating the answer further to give you a bit more information. The `largeHeap=true` shouldn't be considered a fix though. Because the problem may be much bigger. If your application is leaking memory, it will probably break again with heavier use. Check back by tomorrow and the answer will be more robust. Have a good one.